# How do we tell the difference between a prepositional phrase and a particle phrase?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases, particles

From the Farlex Grammar Book, their main difference is that particles cannot introduce a prepositional phrase-a preposition + its object-while a preposition always does.

Please **look over** these proposals. Does *these proposals* function as the object of the preposition *over*, or is *over* merely a particle functioning adverbially with *look*?

He can't **get over** her. Similarly, is *her* the prepositional object of *over*, or is *over* merely a particle?

Comment: The  Farlex Grammar Book has it wrong. After a verb, the constituents of a prepositional phrase are **[verb + [preposition + noun_phrase]]**. But the constituents of a phrasal verb are **[[verb + particle] + noun_phrase]**. True transitive phrasal verbs do Particle Shift: _Please look over these ~ Please look these over_. Prepositional phrases never shift: _He can't get over her_ but not *_He can't get her over._

Comment: "After a verb, the constituents of a prepositional phrase are [verb + [preposition + noun_phrase]]. "
Oftentimes, the particle and preposition take the same form. How then, do we tell the particle and preposition apart?

Some phrasal verbs are unable to shift as well. For instance, we can't invert the sentence from 'my table takes up too much room' to 'my table takes too much room up'.

In this case, it seems that there is no indication as to whether 'up' is a particle or preposition.

Comment: I edited my comment.

Comment: @LeeZhiyuan “my table takes too much room up” isn’t the most natural form, but it still makes sense to me, so “up” is a particle.